# unattended-upgrades never works

Tags: package-management, upgrade, unattended-upgrades

I have installed and configured unattended-upgrades but still every time I run apt-get upgrade, I see there are new packages waiting to be installed. I've waited even 2 weeks for them to get installed automatically but that never happens.

Here are my config files:

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    // Extended Security Maintenance; doesn't necessarily exist for
    // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
    // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
    // should also install from here by default.
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/

```
total 0
```

uname -a

```
Linux 2.6.32-openvz-042stab120.18-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 13 10:33:34 MSK 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

cat /etc/lsb-release

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
```

(It's a server)

sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unattended-upgrades is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

As you can see, there are 4 packages to be upgraded but the unattended-upgrades doesn't do anything.

sudo apt-get --simulate upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 openssl
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libssl-doc [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26] (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [all])
Inst libssl-dev [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26] (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386]) []
Inst libssl1.0.0 [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26] (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386])
Inst openssl [1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.26] (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386])
Conf libssl-doc (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [all])
Conf libssl1.0.0 (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386])
Conf libssl-dev (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386])
Conf openssl (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty-security [i386])
```

Comment: @user535733 there's nothing in /var/lib/apt/periodic/

Comment: @user535733 I added more info to the question. Thanks

Comment: Aha. Making more sense now. Apt and unattended-upgrades have improved a lot in since 14.04. FYI: That's a very unusual and old kernel, and 14.04 LTS reaches EOL during 2019, and there won't be many upgrades in the pipeline. Run a --simulate upgrade, and get the names of the 'not upgraded' packages. That would be a valuable clue.

Comment: @user535733 I understand that it's an old version and I'm planning to upgrade before April but my VPS provider kinda limits me. These things aside, I still think the unattended-upgrades should work on this system. That's not a new package.

Comment: Ah, a VPS. That also explains much. Reminder: The names of the held packages would be a valuable diagnostic clue.

Comment: can you run `sudo /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d` to see what it is doing?